# Find the composition of two relations Rp and Rq

Tags: set-theory, function-and-relation-composition

Let $S_{n}$ be the set of all n-element sets in some universe. 
Given that $R_{k}$ is the relation on $S_{n}$ which is defined as x$R_k$y if and only if the intersection of x and y has at least k elements. We need to find the composition of $R_p$ and $R_q$ where p,q are some natural numbers.

At first I drew a Venn diagram of them and got a system of inequalities, but then I found that the inequalities cannot be solved since the rank is not enough. PS: My method is as following picture:[image: Venn diagram]
So I reached someone who has already solved it for help, but it turned out to be that he just guessed the answer so that he cannot explained how to get it. 
The answer he told me is $R_{p+q-n}$ where n is the index of $S_n$ as mentioned above.
Could you please give me a hint? I’ve already been stuck on this problem for almost a month.

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  For which values have you worked out the composition?

Comment: Thank you for reminding, let me add it.

Comment: The natural place to start here is with examples.  Note that the "official answer" is a bit odd...if $p+q-n<0$, are we to interpret $R_{p+q-n}$ as $R_0$?  If so, then that's a good special case:  Prove that if $p+q≤n$ we have $R_p\circ R_q=R_0$.  If your notation meant something else, please explain.

Comment: Yeah, my notation was just what you meant. For example, when $S_{n}$ is the 3-element set on alphabet, and let $p=q=1$. Then for any subset $x,z$(For example, x=$\{a,b,c\}$, and z=$\{d,e,f\}$), there always exists another subset y=$\{a,d,z\}$ satisfying the conditions. That is, $R_{q}$ on $R_{p}$ is equivalent to $R_{0}$. What I am confused is how to come up with this answer cause it’s really counterintuitive. Thank you again for your dedication, lulu.